# Are all the sentences generated from a probabilistic context-free grammar are grammarly correct?

Tags: parsing, context-free-grammar

By giving a probability to each rule of a context-free grammar, we can get a probabilistic context-free grammar. Now we have a probabilistic context-free grammar and a context-free grammar.

All the sentences are generated from the probabilistic context-free grammar. A grammar recognizer is implemented based on the context-free grammar.

I would like to confirm that the recognizer will think all the generated sentences are syntax-correct. Is it right?

Comment: Just adding probabilities does not make the grammar context sensitive -- a context sensitive grammar is different: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_grammar

Comment: I got your point. How about a probabilistic context-free grammar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you assign a nonzero probability to each of the production rules in a probabilistic CFG, every string that's generated by the PCFG is also something that can be derived from the original CFG. After all, the PCFG has the same rules as the CFG, just with weights assigned that bias the probabilities that particular strings are generated. Therefore, the strings generated will always be syntactically correct provided that the original CFG has the property that all strings generated are syntactically correct.